# how replace " with /" in NSString

Tags: iphone, json, nsstring

I have the below string.

```
"phone" : "555-522-8243",
"name" : "Anna Haro"
```

I want to replace `"`  with `/"`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* yourNewString=  [yourOldaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"/\""];
NSLog(@"\n New String %@",yourNewString);
```

Comment: @user1662494 here you have a type string,, here this is define that this is string which stored in some array or in string... you can get it from direct with index or key name throught

Comment: Don't you want, by accident, to replace `"` with `\"`? Because `/` is not a backslash...

Comment: @user1662494 if its useful then accept the answer and upvote it.. :)

Comment: @H2CO3 yes i know but for some character when we want to log these type of character or implement in string then we can add like this if we want add " then we can add with \"..

Comment: @ParasJoshi i have one more question ... i am having json string . i want to pass it to javascript function ...how can i pass it to javascript function

Comment: i think you want to upload some data to the server or something like that?? if yes then use some links about it http://www.iriphon.com/2011/11/09/ios-uploading-an-image-from-your-iphone-to-a-server/ and http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/upload-image-and-data-with-iphone-sdk/

Comment: @ParasJoshi if i want to replace with \ then what i need to do

Comment: NSString* yourNewString=  [yourOldaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\"]; use this line for that ..:)